# Using google translate with highcharts

Tags: highcharts, google-translate

I am wanting to use highcharts with google translate but google translate wraps all the text it translates in a double font tag which then makes is disappear as this is not recognised by svg.

I can stop it being translated by applying  class=notranslate to the containing div but would really like to have the text translated.

Comment: Can you add a JSFiddle with your code, please?

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/4aL5mksj/1/ I was originally planning to get round this using d3 to give the the flexibility to replace svg text with html text using foreignObject but this is not supported in ie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `useHTML` for your `xAxis` and `yAxis` labels.

To do this:

- go to your `xAxis` and `yAxis` properties
- add the `labels` property to each of them
- add `useHTML: true` to the `labels` property

**Please see working [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4aL5mksj/2/)**

Link to relevant documentation:

- [useHTML property for labels](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.useHTML)
- [HTML in Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting#html)

Please note that the `useHTML` property can be used in some other areas of Highcharts, not only in axis labels. For example, you can use it for data labels on maps or other charts.

Comment: If you adjust the fiddle to: 

 tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.0f}%)<br/>',
            useHTML: true  ,
            shared: true
        },

You can have translated labels    http://jsfiddle.net/4aL5mksj/7/